# CSS: How to toggle switch action on the <a> link?

Tags: html, css

I know that press signal in css is `:active`, but i still can't find a proper way to make a toggle switch for the link.

For example, `<a>` has the color blue, when `<a>` will be pressed first time, it's color should be red, when it is pressed second time, it's color should blue again. So basically first press is a toggle switch from blue to red, and second is vice versa.

I have used `:target` action which didn't seem to work out:

```
a {
    color: blue;
}
a:active {
    color: red;
}
a:target {
    color: red;
}
```

---

How could this be possible without use of JS? So i could toggle switch the link color to red on the first click, and then blue again at the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to achieve without JS. Links are not designed to be toggle elements, and CSS has nothing to track multiple clicks on an element (it is either being clicked or is not).

If you want to represent a toggle, then look at checkbox inputs instead. They have a [`:checked` pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#checked).

Comment: Hello, that would solve the problem, but the style's do not seem to work with the `<input>` element, how could i make it look like a normal paragraph text?

Comment: Style a `<label>` after the associated `<input>`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it via checkboxes and labels.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="t1" class="toggle">
<a href="#"><label for="t1">Link with toggling color</label></a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: -99em;
}

.toggle:not(:checked) + a {
  color: blue;
}

.toggle:checked + a {
  color: red;
}
```

Working example [here](http://jsbin.com/baxiwoqoto/1/edit?html,css,output).

Answer (score 0):

There is one way you could (sort of) achieve this purely with CSS but it would mean that, in its initial state the link would actually be unclickable, which probably wouldn't be desirable.

The trick is to set the [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) of the anchor tag to `none`, wrap it in another element with a [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) attribute (to allow it to gain focus) and then, when the wrapping element receives focus, change the colour of the anchor and reset its `pointer-events`. On the next click, the link will receive focus but this will remove the focus from the wrapping element, which will revert the anchor's styles back to their initial state.

```css
*{color:#000;font-family:sans-serif;outline:0;}
a{
    color:#00f;
    pointer-events:none;
}
span:focus>a{
    color:#f00;
    pointer-events:initial;
}
```

```html
<span tabindex="-1"><a href="#">link</a></span>
```